# Change the column name of dataframe at runtime

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to initialize an empty dataframe with 5 column values. Say column1, column2, column3, column4, column5.

Now I want  to read data from database and want to insert specific column values from the database to this dataframe. Since there are 5 columns its easier to do it individually. But i have to extend the number of columns of the dataframe to 70. For that I am using for loop.

To update the coulmn value I was using 
`dataframe['column "+count+"'] = ....` where count is an incremental variable ranging upto 70.

But the above code adds a new column to the dataframe. How can I use the count variable to access these column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend just using `pandas.io.sql` to download your database data. it returns your data in a `DataFrame`.

but if, for some reason, you want to access the columns, you already have your answer:

assignment: `df['column%d' % count] = data`

retrieval: `df['column%d' % count]`

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to accept the answer so people know it's solved and i get sweet, sweet reputation. or not. up to you.